# Applying the closest value from one list's column to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a 34*3 reference matrix called placement_springs with its 3rd column filled with various angles.
I want to create an other matrix with also angles on the 3rd column. For each cell, I have an exact angle. However, I want to change this 3rd column to the closest value from the 3rd column of the 1st matrix: how can I do that? 
This is what I have right now:

```
separation_springs = np.zeros((springs, 3))
j = 0
Theta_initial = 360/springs
increment = Theta_initial
for j in range(springs):
    while Theta_initial < 361:
        separation_springs[j, 0] = H
        separation_springs[j, 1] = R
        separation_springs[j, 2] = Theta_initial
        Theta_initial = Theta_initial + increment
        j = j + 1

# So I have the initial values of the angles. Now I want to apply each one to a reference value

m = 0
while m < 34:
    if placement_springs[m, 2] - 3 < separation_springs[j, 2] < placement_springs[m, 2] + 3:
        separation_springs[j, 2] == placement_springs[m, 2]
    else:
        m = m + 1
```

Comment: Do you have to use numpy?

Comment: Can you provide us with a minimal example of `placement_springs` and `separation_springs` - maybe a shape of `(10,3)`?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your feedback. Both are angles increasing from a low value (for placement_springs, the initial value is 11.25) to a high value (close to 360 degrees). For example, placement_springs(10,3)= 102,75 degrees

Comment: And no, I don't have to use numpy, it just seemed like the easiest solution; Would you recommend something else?

Comment: "Both are angles increasing from a low value" to clarify, are you saying that the third column in both matrices are *sorted* by increasing angle?

Comment: Yes! Here are the first ten angles for placement_springs:
placement_springs[0, 2] = 10.867,
placement_springs[1, 2] = 34.134,
placement_springs[2, 2] = 40.867,
placement_springs[3, 2] = 49.134,
placement_springs[4, 2] = 55.867,
placement_springs[5, 2] = 64.134,
placement_springs[6, 2] = 70.867,
placement_springs[7, 2] = 94.134,
placement_springs[8, 2] = 100.867,
placement_springs[9, 2] = 109.134,
placement_springs[10, 2] = 115.867